# Web service don't call from objective c, soap request

Tags: php, objective-c, iphone, web-services, soap

does not the call from my iphone app with the service objective my code is as follows:

the web service is in php on http://tuturno.knowit.cl/soap/colas.php and the function is as follows:

```
function registrocola ($param1){
   $obj = json_decode($param1);
   $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   include_once 'RegistroCola.php';
   include_once 'ControlSOAP.php'; 

   $registro = new RegistroCola();
   $registro->cliente = $obj->{'cliente'};
   $registro->cola = $obj->{'cola'};
   $registro->fecha = $hoy;
   $registro->iddispositivo = $obj->{'idDispositivo'};
   $registro->numero = $obj->{'numero'};
   $registro->sucursal = $obj->{'sucursal'};

   $out = ControlSOAP::registrar($registro);

   return $out;}
```

the call from my iphone app is as follows:

```
 // Build dictionnary with parameters
NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionnary setObject:[tiket codigoSucursal] forKey:@"sucursal"];
[dictionnary setObject:[tiket cliente] forKey:@"cliente"];
[dictionnary setObject:[tiket letraCola] forKey:@"cola"];
[dictionnary setObject:[tiket nroTicket] forKey:@"numero"];
[dictionnary setObject:[tiket idDispositivo] forKey:@"idDispositivo"];
[dictionnary setObject:@"2014-11-02" forKey:@"fecha"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL];
NSString *soapAction=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SOAP_ACTION,METHOD_REGISTER];
NSDictionary *headField=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[url host],@"Host",
                         @"text/xml; charset=utf-8",@"Content-Type",
                         soapAction,@"SOAPAction",nil];
// Prepare the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headField];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&theResponse
                                                 error:&errorReturned];
```

to call the service says bad soap request

and this is test call webservice from php

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
  'location' => DatosSOAP::$LOCATION."/colas.php",
  'uri'      => DatosSOAP::$URI,
  'trace'    => 1 ));
$hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $params = array('cliente'=>'99', 'sucursal'=>'99', 'cola'=>'A',            'iddispositivo'=>'Galaxy', 'numero'=>'33', 'fecha'=>$hoy);
 $return = $client->__soapCall("registrocola",array($params));
echo("\nReturning value of __soapCall() call: ".$return);
echo("<br><br><br>\nDumping request headers:\n" 
  .$client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
echo("\nDumping request:\n".$client->__getLastRequest());
echo("\nDumping response headers:\n"
  .$client->__getLastResponseHeaders());
echo("\nDumping response:\n".$client->__getLastResponse());
```

Comment: Does soap service returning XML or JSON? Plese ignore my answer, i will delete that

Comment: the web service returning JSON

Comment: headField you have set as text/XML but both your request and response are JSON. Plese check that part

Answer (score 0):

Does soap service returning XML or JSON?